# Is it true that $|\int_{\Bbb R^n } f d\mu | \ge |\int_{\Bbb R^n} c d\mu |$ if $\mu$ is a complex measure on $\Bbb R^n$ and $f \ge c$?

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ be a complex measure on $\Bbb R^{n}$ and $f \in L^1(\mu)$ such that $ f(x) \ge c > 0 $ ( for some constant $c>0$ ) a.e. $x \in \Bbb R^n$. Then is it true that $$\Big|\int_{\Bbb R^n } f d\mu\Big| \ge \Big|\int_{\Bbb R^n} c d\mu \Big|= c |\mu(\Bbb R^n)| \text{ ? }$$

My first thinking process is to break each integral first in its real and imaginary part and then their corresponding positive and negative parts, i.e. $$\int_{\Bbb R^n } f d\mu = Re\Big(\int_{\Bbb R^n } f d\mu\Big) +i Im \Big(\int_{\Bbb R^n } f d\mu\Big)$$ $$=Re^+\Big(\int_{\Bbb R^n } f d\mu\Big)-Re^-\Big(\int_{\Bbb R^n } f d\mu\Big)+iIm^+\Big(\int_{\Bbb R^n } f d\mu\Big)-iIm^-\Big(\int_{\Bbb R^n } f d\mu\Big)$$ and then wanted to look at corresponding decompositions of the measure and estimate on each such segements. Also note that a complex measure by definition gives $|\mu(\Bbb R^n)| < \infty$ . Now how to proceed from here.

I had recently posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4290786/for-complex-measure-mu-and-0-f-le-g-is-it-true-that-big-int-bbb-rn) . But I realized that the current question is the actual statement that I have managed my problem to boil down to.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick $\mu=2\delta_0 - \delta_1$ and $f(0)=1, f(1)=2$. Then
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f d\mu = 2f(0)-f(1)=2\cdot 1- 1\cdot 2=0.$$
However,
$$\vert \mu(\mathbb{R}^n)\vert =\vert 2-1 \vert =1.$$

This means the inequality is not even true for general signed measures.